# Sentry performance tracing not working with Fastify on Node

Tags: node.js, sentry, fastify

Tried following Sentry's tutorial on adding performance traces but it seems Sentry support is still WIP for Fastify.

Here's what I did based on Sentry's documentation:

```
const sentryIntegrations = [
  new Sentry.Integrations.Http({ tracing: true }),
  ...Sentry.autoDiscoverNodePerformanceMonitoringIntegrations(),
];


Sentry.init({
  dsn: '...',
  enabled: true,
  integrations: sentryIntegrations,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So I needed to use fastify-express as a workaround and then implement this code:

```
import fastifyExpress from '@fastify/express';
import Fastify from 'fastify';
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/node';

const fastifyApp = Fastify();

// notice fastifyExpress registered here
fastifyApp.register(fastifyExpress).after(() => {
  app.use(Sentry.Handlers.requestHandler());
  app.use(Sentry.Handlers.tracingHandler()); // this one will enable the tracing
});
```